# PHP экранирование js кода в тексте HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

Например с чужого сервера приходит нам html - нужно его экранировать от js кода, чтобы потом вставить в таком же виде на сайт. Как это правильно сделать на php? Есть ли встроенная функция? Помимо тегов `<scrip></script>` в HTML элемент может быть встроен тег `onload=""`, `onerror=""`, что еще может послужить xss атаке, как это экранировать?

Comment: Экранировать/удалять нужно абсолютно всё, что не входит в список явно разрешённых вами тегов/атрибутов

Comment: а есть еще теги, атрибуты html которые могут запустить js код?

Comment: Этого никто не может достоверно знать, потому что в будущем могут появиться какие-нибудь новые теги и атрибуты, которые будут запускать js-код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут надо от обратного идти. Надо создать свой whitelist тегов и атрибутов, всё лишнее удалять.

В разных CMS видел разные реализации, у всех свои.

https://github.com/AlexanderGrom/php-qevix тут что-то похожее есть. Указываете теги и атрибуты, которые точно безопасны и не беспокойтесь.

Если держать список опасных тегов и атрибутов, то есть шанс что-то забыть и это будет фатальная ошибка. Могут появиться новые теги и атрибуты опасные.

А в случае с whitelist, всё безопасно. Если какие-то теги безопасные сразу не добавили, их можно всегда добавить без ущерба.